# complex update query SQL using 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, `original` and `updated`.

```
original:

|---------|---------|---------|---------|
|   URL   |   funded|     days|     time|
|---------|---------|---------|---------|

updated



    |---------|---------|---------|---------|
    |   URL   | funded  |   days  |   time  |
    |---------|---------|---------|---------|
```

If two rows (one in table `original` and one in `updated`) have the same `URL`,then I would like to grab `funded` and `days` in the `updated table` and update the `funded` and `days`  in `original table` where the matching URL appears.

Can this be achieved using SQL and how?

Comment: Yes, it can be achieved. In fact, this is a basic and trivial function of SQL. Show us what you've tried and we will gladly point out the mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use MySQL's `UPDATE` join syntax here.

```
UPDATE original a 
INNER JOIN updated b
    ON a.URL = b.URL
SET a.funded = b.funded,
    a.days = b.days
```